# How to get a comprehensive listing of all URLs accessed during a web browsing session?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, safari, history

By "comprehensive" I mean *all* URLs: not only those listed by the typical browser's history function, which I'll refer to as the "primary" URLs, but also all those other URLs accessed by the browser in the process of serving the primary URLs (i.e. redirects, media files, style sheets, scripts, frames, etc.).

(Ideally, the URLs would be organized according to the "primary URL" that led to their being accessed.)

Answer (score 5):

[Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler)

Fiddler is a free web debugging proxy which logs all HTTP(s) traffic between your computer and the Internet. Use it to debug traffic from virtually any application that supports a proxy like IE, Chrome, Safari, Firefox, Opera and more.

Answer (score 2):

I second [the other answer](https://superuser.com/a/771824/245945)'s recommendation for Fiddler.

Additionally, many browsers have "live HTTP header" plugins and other web development tools. Installing these will let you see all requests, often in a nice summary form. Search your browser's plugin repository for ["live HTTP headers"](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/live-http-headers/iaiioopjkcekapmldfgbebdclcnpgnlo?hl=en) (link goes to Chrome plugin - [here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/) is Firefox, [here](http://www.blunck.info/iehttpheaders.html) is one for IE). These types of plugins will give you only information that the browser requests, as opposed to Fiddler which will give you information on everything that every application is requesting (which is great; but you do have to sort through it a bit, not sure what your requirements are).

In Chrome, if you open Tools -> Developer Tools, the "Network" and "Sources" tab will both show you this information, albeit only for the current tab.

In IE (11, at least), the network section in Tools -> F12 Developer Tools will also give you that information.

In Firefox, I do not recall, but I'm sure there is something similar.

In Safari, it seems you can go to [Inspect Elements -> Resource Pane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3596950/parsing-headers-in-safari-something-similar-to-live-http-headers-for-firefox).

None of these, however, really have the ability to generate a nice formatted list without at least some amount of copying / pasting / editing on your part. The built-in browser tools may be the closest as far as associating with a "primary URL" goes, with Live HTTP headers plugins coming in next to monitor just the session (but not so much an association with primary URLs), and Fiddler giving you tons of unsorted information.

Answer (score 1):

For example in Chrome as mentioned by Jason C you can use the Network tab from the web inspector and then right click on any row request "Save as HAR with content".

Then you can save the file and visualize with some tools. Also a drag-and-view tool http://s3u.github.io/har-view/.

And also try online tools.

http://www.speedawarenessmonth.com/what-is-a-har-file-and-what-do-i-use-it-for/

Please refer to the documentation from HAR W3C standard for further information.